# IE 7 how to disable a button after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When have a list of input buttons on the UI which sill submit a form.

New requirement is to `disable` the button after click it. I have tried

```
j("input.allowed-task").each(function() {
document.getElementById(j(this).attr('id')).disabled = true;
});
```

and

```
j("input.allowed-task").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

It all works fine on firefox, IE8, IE9

But when it comes to IE7, neither of above method works. All processes are ignored after the button is disabled, so the form is not even get submit, really don't have an idea how to fix it.

BTW we are on jquery 1.4 so `.prop` is not supported

Comment: What!! If you already have `this`, why do you have to use the ID to get `this` once more, just do `this.disabled` ?

Comment: @adeneo yes it is a waste, just try to get any possible way to make it work in IE7. but failed.

Comment: This worked for me in IE 6: ttp://jsfiddle.net/K2NYs/. Try it with IE 7 to see if it disables the input.

Comment: @fedeetz Thanks, actually I can see the button is disabled on IE7, in my case the button can be disabled as well, but it just the form is not submitted any more. I just want to make the button NOT to be clickable, but doesn't want it totally disfunctional.

Comment: why do you keep IE 7 alive anyway?

Comment: so... you want to disable the button, but still want to submit the form when it's clicked? *\*confused\**

Comment: @KevinB He wants to prevent double-submissions from impatient people...It is quite possible the he has a lot of POST data so the upload might be a bit slow before the page is able to switch to a success page or w/e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd suggest using the submit event rather than click so that you can ensure you catch it, otherwise people can still submit by pressing enter on an input.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    // prevent default so that we completely control when the form submits
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    if ( !$form.data("submitted") ) {
        // form hasn't been submitted yet, set flag, disable button, then submit the form.
        $form.data("submitted",true);
        $("#submitbtn").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
        // obviously disable whatever you need to, 
        // you don't HAVE to disable it though because
        // the flag and e.preventDefault will prevent
        // them from submitting anyway.
        this.submit(); // submits the form, bypassing this submit handler
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You r right about it because if the `disable` event only apply into within click event then user still can click the button even it has been grey out. +1 to disable the buttons within the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should just be able to submit the form in your code directly.

```
j("input.allowed-task").click(function() {

    // disable all buttons
    j("input.allowed-task").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // submit the form
    YOUR_FORM.submit();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
j('input.allowed-task').click(function () {
    // Disable the element
    j(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // Submit the form
    j(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: `.prop('disabled',true)` is the correct way to disable an element with jQuery. you could also have simply done `this.disabled = true`.

Comment: @KevinB Problem is that OP is using an older version of jQuery which doesn't support the use of `.prop`. You're right about using `this.disabled = true`, it would be faster. I just used jQuery to mantain consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Is `replaceWith()` available?

```
j("input.allowed-task").replaceWith('<input type="submit" disabled="disabled">');
```